# Parameter.GetType() - Does the type has to be known at compilation time?

Tags: vb.net, oop, generics, object

is something like this possible - and if so how?

```
    Public Sub CreateGenericList(ByVal SampleObject As Object)
        Dim genericList as new List(Of SampleObject.GetType())
    End Function
```

I want to create a class that is able to deserialize a given XML-file. 
The XML-file contains serialized values of a custom type, which is unknown at compilation time. 
I thought it might be possible to just initialize the class with a parameter SampleObject and to then get that SampleObject's type for all further progressing.
But it seems as if the type for all operations has to be known at compilation time? 
Is there a way around it or can you explain the problem to me?

The code example above is just to illustrate my problem

Thanks for the help,
Janis

Edit:  Your answers might allready have solved the problem, I will read more on the topics "reflection" and "generics" and keep you up to date if i make any progress. So thanks allot for the help.

For those still interested:
I was asked for the purpose of my question and will try to explain it as best i can.

```
    Public Function ReadAllObjects() As List(Of myObjectType)
        Dim result As New List(Of myObjectType)
        Dim ObjectSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(result.GetType)
        Dim FileReader As New System.IO.FileStream(My.Settings.XMLPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
        result = TryCast(ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(FileReader), List(Of myObjectType))
        FileReader.Close()
        RaiseEvent ReadingFinished()
        Return result
    End Function
```

This pretty much sums up what I want to create: A EasyXmlHandling.dll for further use, which will be initialized with the currently used variable type. 
It is then supposed to be able to write and read from/to an XML-File in a really easy way, by just calling "ReadAllObjects" (returns a List of myObjectType) or "AddObject(ByVal theNewObject)"... (more functions)

I got all that to work with a custom class as type, so i could now easily re-use the EasyXmlHandling-code by just replacing that type in the sourcecode with whatever new class i will want to use.
I though would prefer to just call the .dll with a sample object (or the type of it) and to have it do everything else automaticly.

I hope that was understandable, but neither my english nor my technical vocabulary are really good ;)

So thanks again for the help and for reading through this.
I will try to get it to work with all your previous answers and will update the topic when i make further progress.

Comment: You'd need to use generics...something like this `Public Sub CreateGenericList(Of T)(ByVal SampleObject As T) Dim genericList As New List(Of T) End Sub` - syntax may be a bit off, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your actual issue? Why do you need a generic list in your example code and not just `List(Of Object)`? Do you need to call a specific generic method?

Comment: I just edited the original post to elaborate my actual issue. I guess with the hint for "generics" and "reflection" i will be able to get it to work and will (hopefully) require no further help. But feel free to read it and answer on it :)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible (at least, not without using reflection).  The whole point of specifying the type in a generic list, or any other generic type, is so that the compiler can perform compile-time type checking.  If you aren't specifying the type at compile-time, there is no benefit to it at all.  Beyond there being no benefit, it's also simply not supported.  If you don't know the type at compile time, you should just use `Object` instead, since that will work with objects of any type, for instance:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Object)()
```

If you need a list, however, which only allows one type of item, but that type is unknown at compile time, that is possible to do, but you would probably need to create your own non-generic list class for something like that.  As far as I know, there is no non-generic list class provided in the framework which restricts its items to a single specified type.

**Update**

Now that you've explained your reason for doing this, it's clear that generics are your solution.  For instance, you could implement it as as generic function, like this:

```
Public Function ReadAllObjects(Of T)() As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New List(Of T)
    Dim ObjectSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(result.GetType)
    Dim FileReader As New System.IO.FileStream(My.Settings.XMLPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
    result = TryCast(ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(FileReader), List(Of T))
    FileReader.Close()
    RaiseEvent ReadingFinished()
    Return result
End Function
```

Then, you could call it, like this, passing it which ever type you want:

```
Dim cars As New List(Of Car) = ReadAllObjects(Of Car)()
Dim boats As New List(Of Boat) = ReadAllObjects(Of Boat)()
```

As you can see, that is the whole purpose of generics.  They are a very powerful tool when you any to keep your code type-specific, but still be able to re-use it with different types.  Reflection, on the other-hand is not a good fit in this particular situation.  Reflection is also very useful, but should always be considered an option of last resort.  If there is another way to do it, without reflection, that's usually the better way.

Comment: You can easily create types `List(Of T)` on runtime using reflection. However, in that particular case I would consider making the method generic itself.

Comment: *No, that is not possible*: Well, you *could* create the "right" `List(Of T)` using reflection...

Comment: @DominicKexel Good point.  Yes, it is possible to do it that way, but then you'd have to reference the list object as `IList` or `Object`, which would defeat much of the point.  I agree with your original comment--Janis needs to explain the reason *why* this is desired.  Chances are, it's misguided, but there is a slight chance there is a good reason for it :)

Comment: I just edited the original post to elaborate my actual issue. I guess with the hint for "generics" and "reflection" i will be able to get it to work and will (hopefully) require no further help but just more time to understand. But feel free to read it and answer on it :) Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the update and especially for the very detailed code snippet. I accepted your post as answer. This topic taught me a new means of programming that I will hopefully be able to use allot in the future. So let's hope that others will also read this and learn something of it. Great help, well appreciated! :)